# Cell style inheritance and specifying the same style twice

Tags: bugs, stylesheet, style

#### Bug introduced in V11.1 or earlier and persists through V11.3

> [CASE:4061571], confirmed

Consider the following three examples of a cell:

```
CellPrint@Cell["i", "Section"]
CellPrint@Cell[BoxData@InterpretationBox[Cell@"i", 2], "Section"]
CellPrint@Cell[BoxData@InterpretationBox[Cell@"i", 2], "Section", "Section"]
```

which yields:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice how the second cell has some strange mixture of styles applied. According to the documentation of [`Cell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cell.html):

> `Cell[contents,"style1","style2",…]`
> represents a cell with multiple styles applied to it.

So there should be nothing special about the third line.

While I am pretty sure that this is a bug, I have noticed that the documentation pages all do the same thing for their heading cells:

```
Cell[
  TextData[{…,"Basic Examples",…}],
  "ExampleSection",
  "ExampleSection",
  WholeCellGroupOpener->True
]
```

So I'm not so sure anymore where the issue lies. This brings me to the purpose of this question:

- What is happening in the second/third example?
- Why are only some styles applied, but not others?
- Why is the reasoning behind applying the same style twice? (and why does it make a difference?)
- Is this behavior documented anywhere?

Comment: I'd report this one too. Are you planning to do so with those 3 topics?

Comment: @Kuba already did (I'll update the posts once I get an answer) - I know that this is not the place to post bug reports, but I figured I'd post them anyway in the hopes of getting more insight and possibly a workaround. Also, I'm still not too used to working with Cell and Box expressions, so I assumed there's a significant chance that I've simply missed something in the docs ;)

Comment: It depends, I'm posting 95% of bugs I find because it may help future readers, I also want to put pressure on WRI but I don't hope for much :). It is good to know something is a bug and not e..g your lack of knowledge.

Comment: You can kinda think of your multi-style specification as more like {"Section", styles dictated by the FrontEnd, "Section", ...}.  An example of a style that the FrontEnd can inject is "StandardForm"/"TraditionalForm".  It's not that simple, but that is the general gist.

Comment: @ihojnicki do you have any reference for this with a bit more information about what's going on?

Comment: @Mathe172 I would be surprised if that particular behavior was described anywhere.

Comment: @ihojnicki That's unfortunate, but I was afraid you'd say something like that... All the more thanks to you in that case!

Comment: @ihojnicki and Mathe172 I'd say it is explicitly against StylesAndTheInheritanceOfOptionSettings which sets the hierarchy quite clearly. I can live with 'hidden' styles (for DocekdCells/InlineCells) and the fact that they are inserted between Cell's and Notebook's options but in this case they are inserted between Cell's styles making the first style very special. [The discussion about documenting all those exceptions is not new](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14835/5478). Maybe there is no huge demand, or maybe there is no demand because people are discouraged by apparent randomness?

Comment: @Kuba Interesting...  I didn't know about that post by John.  Which by the way is the answer to this question.  In the example above, its step two that causes the difference in appearance.

Comment: @ihojnicki you are right, I missed that even though I knew. (otoh unless you see the source code you could argue that step two could 'patched' by 9th anyway)

Comment: @Kuba thanks a lot for the link! That does indeed explain what's happening here. I've voted to close this question as a duplicate - if the vote doesn't pass, I'll probably add a short answer based on the linked one (if I don't forget)