# Setting default font size

Tags: stylesheet

Say I want to create a new stylesheet that would be based on some preexisting stylesheet. The first thing I'd like to do is to set some initial font size globally by:

```
Cell[StyleData[All], FontSize->12]
```

However, I can now no longer change the size of any cell (although it appears to change in stylesheet editor it doesn't in the notebook). In other words, this no longer works:

```
Cell[StyleData["Title"], FontSize->22]
```

What am I doing wrong and why?

Comment: I think this is the answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13785/5478

Comment: Thank you, it indeed seems to be a similar problem.